# React: how to call a method from a function

Tags: reactjs

I have this class:

```
import { useTranslation, Trans } from 'react-i18next'

export default function getLanguage(){
    const i18n = useTranslation()
    return i18n.resolvedLanguage
}
```

When calling `getLanguage` from a different file, e.g. textReducer.js:

```
import getLanguage from '../languages/LanguageHandler'

export const getText = (state, id) => {
    console.log(getLanguage)
    return state.text[id]
}
```

the console log is `undefined`, whereas the expected result should be 'en'.

Comment: Presumably the error is due to the name _not_ indicating it's a hook - call it `useLanguage` (and note there's no point destructuring `t` to be completely ignored).

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand your question. If you want to create the getLanguage as a component that can be re-used for later. Do it like this.

```
import { useTranslation, Trans } from 'react-i18next'
export default function getLanguage(){
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()
    return i18n.resolvedLanguage
}
```

Then in your other functional component or class component, you can import the getLanguage and use it as a component.

Comment: I edited the question with the current version. Right now, when calling `getText` the console logs `undefined`, and it should be 'en' or any language that the browser is set to